# Tried to read XML stored into DE as text and print but it output is null

Tags: ampscript, xml

Code:

```
%%[
var @xml,@email

set @email=email

set @xml=xml
]%%

Emial:%%=v(@email)=%%

XML=%%=v(@xml)=%%
```

DE:

```
email                      |         xml

ssingh297@sapient.com      |         <from>Jani</from>
```

Response:

[image]

Comment: what you want  you need stored data in xml format in Datextension ?.

Comment: Just i want to print it as a text for now

Comment: iam asking your input data coming in which format  like xml or text

Comment: It is stored in DE so it should be in text format

Comment: pkharries i think it is not printing the XML but it hold that XML because when i parse it and then print the value it printing the value

Comment: your are parsing xml to text the text  stored into  DE ?